# How to boil milk without a pot?

Tags: food, kitchen, substitute-tool, temperature, drinks

How to boil milk for a cup of coffee without a pot?

Kettle sounds reasonable, but it's difficult to clean it after use.

Comment: Do you have a microwave?

Comment: A microwave is best. If you use a kettle or a little immersion coil you will never get the milk off it.

Comment: Yes, microwave could be an option if it won't explode. Last time when I've tried, I've broke my favorite mug.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of people making coffee with milk.  Is it better than using water then adding cream?

Comment: @Minnow In the UK, at least, almost everyone who has a white coffee will use milk.

Comment: @Minnow In local cafes they never use water (e.g. Starbucks, Nero, Eat), but only hot milk.

Comment: I done learned something today.  Guess what I'm going to try tomorrow!

Comment: @Duncan: nope, not true - I'm in the UK and most of the coffee I drink, apart from cappucinno is what's called Americano - black with a dash of milk or cream. A common choice in order to avoid all that unhealthy milk...

Comment: @Bamboo Sorry, I meant milk rather than cream *but in an americano*. I didn't realise we were discussing lattes.

Comment: @Duncan - ah, seems I mistook your comment - given the original question was about boiling milk for coffee, I assumed you meant we all drank all milk coffee in the UK. On rereading your comment, that's not what you're really saying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microwave is your best bet. If it exploded last time, it might have been the container. First, get a new container and [test](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20test%20for%20microwave%20safe) that it's microwave safe. Add your milk and a few coffee grounds to create a non-uniform volume so it won't get superheated. Nuke until boiling.
If you don't want to go the microwave route, I can think of an alternative but it takes a while and won't technically boil the milk but it *will* get it pretty close. Put your milk in a container and place that inside a larger container (like a cup inside a big measuring bowl). Boil water through your favorite means and pour it into the large container. Stir a bit and wait for the heat transfer. Repeat with fresh boiling water until the milk is hot enough. I use this to heat frozen breast milk - not to boiling, of course - and it works but it's tedious. Microwave is still the way to go for a daily routine.

Comment: I microwave mine all the time. I also take a balloon whisk, put it in the milk and roll the whisk between my hands, frothing the milk up really well.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite method, in absence of microwave, is to **place your mug directly onto electric oven stove**.

For example to make a coffee, add instant coffee and pour into your mug boiled water (e.g. kettle) to warm your mug (1/3, 2/3 or optional), pour the milk (other rest), place the mug on the stove and set the heat to minimum power (otherwise your mug could break of heat) and relax. It's a bit slower method, but having your whole mug hot, your coffee stay warm for longer.
See example:
[image: set it and relax]

---

Or if you don't have electric oven, buy a alcohol stove (such as [Zelph Starlyte Stove](http://www.woodgaz-stove.com/starlyte-stove.php)).

[image: The StarLyte Stove]
[image: The Starlyte with a 10cm IMUSA mug and Zelph's lid]

Or create your own. Here are the instructions:

**Super Cat Alcohol Stove**

1. Find or buy some small cheap food in aluminium can, e.g. cat food.

   [image: Fancy Feast - Tender Beef & Chicked Feast Classic]
2. Empty the container (by giving to your neighbour's cat if you don't have) and make some small holes as below.

   [image]
   [image]
3. Add some fuel or alcohol (e.g. [spiritus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denatured_alcohol)) and set on fire (on some safe ground).

   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Source: [Super Cat Alcohol Stove](http://www.frontageroads.com/2011/09/27/super-cat-alcohol-stove/) at Frontage Roads

---

See also:

- [Zelph Starlyte alcohol stove](http://www.backpackinglight.com/cgi-bin/backpackinglight/forums/thread_display.html?forum_thread_id=87023) at backpackinglight forum

Answer (score 1):

Try powdered milk. Boil the water in the microwave in a cup, then add the powdered milk afterward. Usually, powdered milk has a poor taste only when drinking it straight. When used as an ingredient or mixing there is usually no poor taste.

Comment: Does it dissolve well? As good as Coffee-mate or as bad as flour in water?